# Compilando C para binário bruto

Tags: c, compilação, assembly

Como compilar um código em C para baixo nível? (`.bin`, exemplo).

Estou utilizando a IDE Code::Blocks, e o compilador minGW (estou no Windows, mas caso saiba para Linux os comandos são praticamente idênticos).

Comment: O que é C baico nível? Faça a pergunta do *inline assembly* separada desta, é outro assunto. Aqui não passamos apostilas, só respondemos perguntas específicas. Se quiser alguma informação nesse sentido, olhe a *tag*: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Comment: Você vai fazer a pergunta do *inline assembly*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se entendi, você quer gerar um arquivo binário bruto, sem um formato dependente de sistema operacional. Se for isto, é uma pergunta muito básica para algo que é apenas a ponta do *iceberg*, não é simples mexer com isto, mas tudo bem, dá para responder.

Você já sabe que não poderá usar nenhuma função que dependa de chamadas de sistema? Nem mesmo indiretamente. Você terá que tratar algumas coisas na mão, já que o compilador presume certas condições. Quase compensa fazer em *assembly* mesmo.

Para compilar não muda nada. Para *linkar* muda. Pode fazer isto também:

```
cc -c main.c
objcopy -O binary main.o main.bin
```

Verifique assim:

```
objdump -d main.o
hexdump -C main.bin
```

Tem que ser igual.

Provavelmente você está querendo [estudar isso aqui](http://wiki.osdev.org/Expanded_Main_Page). [Especialmente isso](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_bones#Writing_a_kernel_in_C).

Comment: Excelente, obrigado....Enquanto ao inline Assembly, eu consegui conteúdo que falava sobre e já entendi como é. Obrigado. o/

Comment: Mas se quiser perguntar pra deixar registrado aqui, seria legal, você pode postar a resposta também.

Answer (score -1):

Usa a opção -S do gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.2/gcc_2.html#SEC4

> -S
>      Stop after the stage of compilation proper; do not assemble. The output is in the form of an assembler code file for each non-assembler input file specified.
>
> By default, the assembler file name for a source file is made by replacing the suffix '.c', '.i', etc., with '.s'.
>
> Input files that don't require compilation are ignored.